# Combination Of Text and Image in Text View (Android App)

Tags: image, layout, textview

[image]

I want to Add Facebook logo & Google Logo to the Left of their Text Facebook & Google in their Text View respectively.

For that:

selected View >> attribute : drawableLeft >> Choose Image.

But the Result is:

[image]

Result Required is:

[image]

*Can Check Code from Here: https://github.com/DumbestWalls/MeowPanda

*Import Code: https://github.com/DumbestWalls/MeowPanda.git

Answer (score 0):

So, It's Been Solved Now.

All I had to Do is to Resize the logo.

Thanks For Your time.